# Are there some algorithms which don't support efficient parallel implementation?

Tags: multithreading, algorithm, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

It's a very simple research question I'm interested in. Are there some examples of algorithms, or just some code which can be implemented effectively sequentially but doesn't support efficient parallelization?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about algorithms in general, not a programming problem.

Comment: It is not known whether NC = P (ie there may be (or not) some algorithm in P that is not in NC, and thus not efficiently parallelizable), if that's what you're asking (which is unclear).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure there are - lots of algorithms simply can't be parallelized due to its sequential nature. You have several good examples in cryptography.

Good examples are the cipher block chaining algorithm (CBC), Propagating cipher-block chaining (PCBC), cipher feedback, and output feedback. Have a look at the wikipedia page about block cipher modes of operation; for each mode, there's a small box on the top right saying whether the encryption and decryption process are parallelizable: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation

In general, any algorithm on which the next step depends on the previous step outcome can't be parallelized, at least efficiently. You could always have multiple threads working on it, but it wouldn't be of much use, you'd have to wait for the previous step to finish before moving on, so you never really have true parallelism.

There are surely several other examples, cryptography is just one of them and the one I could think of immediately.

Answer (score 1):

Simple algorithm as swapping two numbers cannot be made parallel, in fact most of basic algorithms cannot be made parallel. Hence any algorithm which made up of sequence of dependent steps made from these simple algorithms cannot be made parallel.

Comment: Non sequitur in that reasoning. Assume Algorithm A "1. Swap numbers A and B; 2. Swap numbers C and D". Made up of a basic non-parallel algorithm (your example), but can very easily be parallelized.

Comment: @Voo The algorithm should be made up of sequence of simple algorithm here means 2. should be dependent on 1. for example 1. swap(A,B) 2. swap(B,C).

Comment: Yes, that's my point: You cannot parallelize a sequence of dependent steps, but you certainly can parallelize an algorithm that's made up of non-parallelizeable parts.

Comment: @Voo my point here was you cannot parallelize a sequence of dependent unparallelizable steps.

Comment: Yes and I just pointed out that the way it's phrased does not coincide with the intended meaning.